# org-agenda bulk deschedule

Tags: org-agenda

I'm trying to extend the bulk action in org-agenda to include a de-scheduling action

I have

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-bulk-custom-functions
             '(?n (lambda nil  (org-schedule '(4)))))
```

but it doesn't appear to do anything. I'm using evil bindings so `C-u B s` doesn't work, besides I'd like to figure out the correct elisp. How do I correctly apply `(org-schedule '(4))` to an item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `org-agenda-schedule` like:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-bulk-custom-functions
             '(?n (lambda () (interactive) (org-agenda-schedule '(4)))))
```

Comment: Awesome. That works